# How can I install a specific gcc or gcc-5-base on a ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, gcc

I am trying to install libgeos-dev on ubuntu 16.04

This command

```
apt-get install libgeos-dev
```

get this error

```
# apt-get -f install libgeos-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 is to be installed
 g++-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 is to be installed
 gcc-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 is to be installed
 gfortran-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 is to be installed
```

`apt-get install gcc-5=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11` get the same error as above.

This command

```
# apt-get install gcc-5=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11 \
> gcc-5-base=2.2.20-1ubuntu1~16.04.11
```

get this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.2.20-1ubuntu1~16.04.11' for 'gcc-5-base' was not found
```

this question is different from that [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

as I said previously, `apt-get -f` does not work, and I am work on a CLI server which does not have GUI.

how can I install the dependencies?

Comment: Is your package catalog up to date (i.e. did you run `sudo apt-get update` before attempting to install)?

Comment: @steeldriver yes. I did update.